# How to create a dictionary out of my specific dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe df with column name:

```
names
phil/andy    
allen
john/william/chris
john
```

I want to turn it into sort of "dictionary" (pandas dataframe)  with unique random number for each name:

```
name     value
phil      1
andy      2
allen     3
john      4
william   5
chris     6
```

How to do that? dataframe is sample, so I need a function to do same thing with very large dataframe

Comment: @Stücke its first 4 rows of dataset (basically .head(4))

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? a dictionary? a dataFrame? it's not clear...

Comment: @Nick a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Original pd.DataFrame

d = {'phil': [1],
     'phil/andy': [2],
     'allen': [3],
     'john/william/chris': [4],
     'john': [5]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Append all names to a list

names = []

for col in df.columns:
    
    names = names + col.split("/")

# Remove duplicated names from the list

names = [i for n, i in enumerate(names) if i not in names[:n]]

# Create DF

df = pd.DataFrame(
    # Random numbers
    np.random.choice(
        len(names), # Length
        size = len(names), # Shape
        replace = False # Unique random numbers
        ),
    # Index names
    index = names,
    # Column names
    columns = ['Rand value']
    )
```

If you want to create a dictionary instead of a pd.DataFrame you can also apply `d = df.T.to_dict()` in the end. If you want numbers `0,1,2,3,...,n` instead of random numbers you can replace `np.random.choice()` with `range()`.

Comment: its the same thing as creating new column by hand. what if there are thousands rows

Comment: have you run it? its wrong

Comment: Can you specify? Works for me. You're not very precise in what you want.

Comment: If you want the names in the columns and not in the index you can apply `df = df.reset_index()` in the end.